# External lib not found when deploy on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using a couple of google libs in order to authenticate with firebase in a Python + GAE app.
I have configured the requirements.txt with the following content:

```
google-auth==1.0.1
requests==2.14.2
requests-toolbelt==0.7.1
```

This is what I am importing:

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
```

When I run pip install, they do get installed locally and I get no errors.

[local libs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpjkA.png)

But when I try to deploy this application to Google App Engine, all those external libs get the same errors. GAE doesn't find the files:

```
ImportError: No module named auth.transport.requests
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide your library directory to the `google.appengine.ext.vendor.add()` method.

Create a file named `appengine_config.py` in the same folder as your `app.yaml` file.

Edit the `appengine_config.py` file and provide your library directory to the vendor.add() method.

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library